# PhpStorm 2016.1 Theme issue

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

[image: its PhpStorm2016.1]

Kindly tell me how to change its pointed section in image change back to default.

Answer (score 2):

You can change GUI Theme at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance | Theme`

[image]

Alternatively -- `View | Quick Switch Scheme` and then choose `6. Look and Feel` option.

---

The editor area colors (Editor Scheme) can be changed at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts`

Alternatively -- `View | Quick Switch Scheme` and then choose `1. Color Scheme` option.